# Apache Nifi processor to update JSON data before returning into HandleHttpResponse

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

My Apache processor setup is **`HandleHttpRequest`** -> **`InvokeHTTP`** ->**`HandleHttpResponse`**.

I'm hitting an API from Postman which invokes another API and gets the JSON data and returns.

Now in between **`InvokeHTTP`** -> **`HandleHttpResponse`**, I'm trying to add another processor which modifies data before returning a response.

My JSON is from **`InvokeHTTP`**

```json
{
   "id": 1,
   "menuTempId": 28,
   "conceptId": 252,
   "menuId": 1,
   "currency": "SAR",
   "language": "En",
   "updatedAt": 1695114353000,
   "countryId": "SA",
   "version": "v1",
   "categories": [
      {
         "position": 5,
         "id": 367,
         "name": "Our New",
         "isHidden": 0,
         "is_toggle": 0,
         "products": [
            {
               "id": 2724,
               "position": 3,
               "name": "Electric Lemonade",
               "services": null,
               "inSide": 0
            },
            {
               "id": 2725,
               "position": 4,
               "name": "Electric Lemonade 2",
               "services": null,
               "inSide": 0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "position": 4,
         "id": 368,
         "name": "Our New 2",
         "isHidden": 0,
         "is_toggle": 0,
         "products": [
            {
               "id": 2726,
               "position": 3,
               "name": "Electric Lemonade3",
               "services": null,
               "inSide": 0
            },
            {
               "id": 2727,
               "position": 4,
               "name": "Electric Lemonade 4",
               "services": null,
               "inSide": 0
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to modify it to look like this:

```json
{
   "id": 1,
   "currency": "SAR",
   "language": "En",
   "countryId": "SA",
   "version": "v1",
   "categories": [
      {
         "position": 4,
         "id": 368,
         "name": "Our New 2",
         "products": [
            {
               "id": 2726,
               "position": 3,
               "name": "Electric Lemonade3"
            },
            {
               "id": 2727,
               "position": 4,
               "name": "Electric Lemonade 4"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to remove a few keys from JSON data. I have tried using **`UpdateAttribute`** -> **`JoltTransformJSON`**, but it's not working.

Can you help me understand from which processor and configuration I can achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only adding a ***JoltTransformJSON*** processor along with the following specification

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id|currency|language|countryId|version": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

is enough.

Where the pipe operators are used similar to they're(or double pipes are) used in some well-known programming languages as **OR** operators and the ampersand stands for replicating the values of those keys.

**Edit** : Yes, you can get the latest desired output as well. Use the transformation below due to the need of arbitrarily chosen object among objects of the `products` array such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "categories": "=lastElement"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id|currency|language|countryId|version": "&",
      "categories": {
        "position|id|name": "&1[0].&",
        "products": {
          "*": {
            "id|position|name": "&3[0].&2[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros Özhanr! It worked. I've updated my JSON. Can you help me remove a key from an array?

Comment: Hi @NehaVerma, what's the rule for it, do you always want to remove the first object, or to keep always only the last one? Btw, does the "categories" array always have two main objects ?

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan, categories array can have multiple objects. I want to make conditions like the position 5 object should be removed or the position 4 object should be removed. Something like that. Similarly, I want to check for inside category objects as well for product arrays to remove a few keys from product objects as well. Is it possible in Apache Nifi?

Comment: Thank you very much Barbaros Özhan, this worked for me. Also, now I'm able to understand how to work with nested object in apache nifi.

Comment: Suppose I want to modify the array of objects entirely without the first and last elements. Then I'm trying to apply this rule. It works partially but does not show data inside the categories array; it creates its own index. "0": [], "1":[]. @Barbaros

[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id|currency|language|countryId|version": "&",
      "categories": {
        "*": {
          "position|id|name": "&1[0].&",
          "products": {
            "*": {
              "id|position|name": "&3[0].&2[&1].&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Comment: @NehaVerma 1st : Seems that you missed the asterisks for the keys before `": { "position|id|name"` and `": { "id|position|name":`, 2nd : The lately shared spec doesn't yields the result as you mentioned even if those asterisk are added.

Comment: Yes, the result is not what I was expecting. Also, asterisks are not missed, I wasn't able to send them into the comment actually. Is my rule incorrect? @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: @NehaVerma Then(if not important to pick first/last but only single) just fix the index beneath `"catergories"` array to `0` such as `[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id|currency|language|countryId|version": "&",
      "categories": {
        "0": {
          "position|id|name": "&2[0].&",
          "products": {
            "*": {
              "id|position|name": "&4[0].&2[&1].&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]`

Answer (score 1):

this jolt definition should work for you:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id":        "id",
      "currency":  "currency",
      "language":  "language",
      "countryId": "countryId",
      "version":   "version"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use **remove** operation to delete the unwanted properties from the JSON in ***JoltTransformJSON***.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "menuTempId|conceptId|menuId|updatedAt": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Praveen kumar, it worked. I have updated my JSON, can you help me with array remove key too.